# Align three elements in a row

Tags: html, css

I'd like to place my image to the left, text in center and other text on the right.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="author">

    <img src='http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif' height='70' width='70' />

    <p>Center</p>

    <p class="date">Right</p>

</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yx5z1rr6/

Comment: Float it? Or if you want it justified across the parent, use flexbox.

Comment: You haven't actually provided any code that shows what you've attempted. All you've done is made a request for others to do your work for you.

Comment: I was concerned Flexbox wasn't 100% across all browsers - even the more recent IE releases.

Comment: @zzzzBov Apologies. I'll update my Fiddle with my existing CSS.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Does my answer work for you?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yx5z1rr6/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx5z1rr6/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="author">
    <div class="sample">
        <img src='http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif' height='70' width='70' />
    </div>
    <div class="sample">
        <p>Center</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sample">
        <p class="date">Right</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.author {
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    background:red;
}
.sample{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
```

What I have done in the fiddle is that, I enclosed each of your elements, ie `<p>` and the `<img>` inside a `<div>` with class `sample` and then in the CSS for `.sample` I floated them to left and gave a width of 33%.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float`s this way:

```css
.author {
  width: 600px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.author img, .author p {
  float: left;
}

.author p.date {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="author">
  <img src='http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif' height='70' width='70' />
  <p>Center</p>
  <p class="date">Right</p>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yx5z1rr6/5/**

This solution is **without using flexbox**, so it works on IE too. Or if the center one is a perfect center use this:

```css
.author {
  width: 600px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.author img {
  float: left;
}

.author p {
  text-align: center;
}

.author p.date {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="author">
  <img src='http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif' height='70' width='70' />
  <p class="date">Right</p>
  <p>Center</p>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yx5z1rr6/5/**

Comment: Many thanks for this. If I wanted to center align the text `center`, how do I achieve this?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Check the second snippet. It does it.

Answer (score 1):

I like so much the flexbox design!

easy and fast look this code, i just added some lines more

```css
.author {
    width:600px;
    background:red;
    width: 600px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="author">
    
    <img src='http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif' height='70' width='70' />
    
    <p>Center</p>

    <p class="date">Right</p>

</div>
```

if you want more information about flex design see this [link](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto) (for test) and  [this in csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (for learn)

Answer (score 0):

use inline-block. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tshc6qo/)

```css
.author {
    width:600px;
    background:red;
   margin:0!important;
    padding:0!important;
}
img, p{display:inline-block;}

img{width:70px; padding-left:5px;padding-top:15px;}
p{width:225px; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="author">
    
    <img src='http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif' height='70' width='70' />
    
    <p>Center</p>

    <p class="date">Right</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be: http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/yx5z1rr6/8/

HTML

```
<div class="boxes"> 
   <div class="one box"><img src='http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif' height='70' width='70' /></div> 
   <div class="two box">Center</div> 
   <div class="three box date">Right</div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxes { 
   width:50%; 
   margin:0 auto; 
} 
.box { 
   display:inline-block; 
   width:24%; 
   height:15em; 
   text-align:center; 
   line-height:15em; 
   color:#000; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:100%; height:20%;">
    <div style="background-color:red;">
        <img src="http://www.lua.org/images/lua-logo.gif" width="128" height="128" alt="Image" style="float:left;"/>
        <div style="float:left; margin-left:40%;">
            <p>Center Text</p>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;">
            <p>Right Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```